# null при отправке модели

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Всем здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой:мне в приложении надо добавить товар в БД, при этом заранее не известно сколько у него будет разных описаний(характеристик) по этому есть 2 таблицы - Товары и Характеристики. При добавлении нового товара, надо отправлять на сервер форму товара и коллекцию характеристик. Я для этого сделал общую модель. Но когда я нажимаю submit и проверяю dev tools, там я вижу, что модель Товар отправляется, а Характеристики и близко нет. Где моя ошибка?
Ниже выложу листинг моделей, кода сервера и вьюшки.

Модель товаров:

```
public partial class bs_parts
{
    public bs_parts()
    {
        this.bs_details = new HashSet<bs_details>();
        this.bs_images = new HashSet<bs_images>();
        this.bs_orders = new HashSet<bs_orders>();
    }

    public decimal parts_id { get; set; }
    public decimal parts_category_id { get; set; }
    public decimal parts_brand_id { get; set; }
    public string parts_model { get; set; }
    public double parts_price { get; set; }
    public int parts_amount { get; set; }

    public virtual bs_brands bs_brands { get; set; }
    public virtual bs_categories bs_categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<bs_details> bs_details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<bs_images> bs_images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<bs_orders> bs_orders { get; set; }
}
```

Модель характеристик:

```
public partial class bs_details
{
    public decimal details_id { get; set; }
    public string details_name { get; set; }
    public string details_value { get; set; }
    public decimal details_part_id { get; set; }

    public virtual bs_parts bs_parts { get; set; }
}
```

И общая модель:

```
public class AddPartViewModel
{
    public bs_parts part { get; set; }
    public List<bs_details> detail { get; set; }
    public bs_images image { get; set; }
}
```

Код серверной стороны:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePart(AddPartViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(_db.bs_categories, "categories_id", "categories_name");
        ViewBag.Brands = new SelectList(_db.bs_brands, "brands_id", "brands_name");
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model.part != null)
        {
            model.part.parts_brand_id = 3;
            model.part.parts_category_id = 3;
            _db.bs_parts.Add(model.part);
            if (model.detail != null)
            {
                foreach (var details in model.detail)
                {
                    details.details_part_id = 8;
                    _db.bs_details.Add(details);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage!=null)
            {
                byte[] imageData = null;
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
                }
                model.image.image_part_id = model.part.parts_id;
                model.image.images_image = imageData;
                _db.bs_images.Add(model.image);

            }
            //добавить else if () {...} если модель есть, а изображения нет
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
        <p>
            Выбрать категорию:
            @Html.DropDownList("Categories");
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Выбрать производителя:
            @Html.DropDownList("Brands");
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Название модели:
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.part.parts_model)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.part.parts_model)
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Цена:
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.part.parts_price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.part.parts_price)
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Количество:
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.part.parts_amount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.part.parts_amount)

        </p>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="~/Controllers/AdminController.cs">
    <div class="details">
       <div class="details-part">
        <input class="details_name" type="text" />
        <input class="details_value" type="text" />
       </div>
    </div>
    <div><p><a class="plus">Add detail</a></p></div>

<div>
    <input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="details"/>
<div>
    <button id="save-form">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Скрипт отправки и добавления новых полей:

```
<script>
var $myForm = $("#myForm");

$(".plus").off("click").on("click", function () {
    $(".details").append('<div class="details-part">  <input class="details_name" type="text" /> <input class="details_value" type="text" /> </div>')
});

$("#save-form").off("click").on("click", function () {
    var detailList = [];
    $myForm.find(".details-part").each(function () {
        detailList.push({
            details_value: $(this).find(".details_value").val(),
            details_name: $(this).find(".details_name").val()
        })
    });
    $myForm.find('[name="details"]').val(JSON.stringify(detailList))
    $myForm.submit()
});
```

В таком варианте detail приходит null, но если поменять и сделать так:

```
        <input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
        <input name="detail[0].details_value" type="text" />

        <input name="detail[1].details_name" type="text" />
        <input name="detail[1].details_value" type="text" />

        <input name="detail[2].details_name" type="text" />
        <input name="detail[2].details_value" type="text" />
```

То на сервер приходит 3 объекта detail и все ок. Проблема будет, если я захочу удалить объект в середине, тогда порядок нарушится. Мне уже подсказали, что можно не удалять, а сделать поля hidden, а на сервере уже делать проверку на пустое поле. Я в JS не в зуб ногой, может кто-то, у кого есть свободное время и желание, помочь написать скрипт такой, чтобы он добавлял новые поля и при "удалении" делал их hidden. С добавлением я справлюсь, а вот со вторым проблемы.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у вас `AddPartViewModel` - используется на вьюшке. А когда у вас открывается страница, у вас `detail` в модели случайно не `null`?

Comment: @DenisBubnov detail null, а part модель приходит
У меня получается вручную отправлять, когда я использую такие поля с идентификаторами <input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
Но а если скриптом добавить несколько таких, а потом я захочу удалить что-то из середины, то порядок нарушится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для случая, когда вы генерируете инпуты для списка объектов, и не гарантируете последовательность индексов (например при удалении  некоторых элементов), то можете использовать свойство `index`:

```
<input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="0"/>     
<input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
<input name="detail[0].details_value" type="text" />

<input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="1"/>     
<input name="detail[1].details_name" type="text" />
<input name="detail[1].details_value" type="text" />

<input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="2"/>     
<input name="detail[2].details_name" type="text" />
<input name="detail[2].details_value" type="text" />
```

с использованием этого поля в вашу модель попадут все данные, вне зависимости от пропусков номеров. В общем случае, ваши индексы могут быть даже не числовыми, например:

```
<input name="detail.Index" type="hidden" value="test"/>     
<input name="detail[test].details_name" type="text" />
<input name="detail[test].details_value" type="text" />
```